# Travel to Romania with a residence permit of Germany

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, romania

I am a student in Germany and i have a residence permit here for 2 years, which is also a Schengen visa, I suppose. Do I need a separate visa if i wish  to travel to Romania?

Answer (score 6):

No you do not need a separate visa to visit Romania. Please consult this [link](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040) for more information. But make sure your visa does not expire when you are in Romania.

> V. Do I need a visa?
>
> 2. NO
>
> ​The holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national
> visas or residence permits issued by Schengen Member States.
>
> Attention! The number of entries as well as the right of stay
> established as per the Schengen visas must not have been exhausted.
> The right of stay on the territory of Romania shall not exceed the
> right of stay granted as per the visas/residence permits issued by the
> Schengen Member States.

Answer (score 0):

Your residence permit is not a Schengen visa. However, as stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=ro&SUBSECTION=VS&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a residence permit issued by Bulgaria,
>     Croatia, Cyprus or a **Schengen Member State**

So no, you do **not** need a visa for Romania, just present your passport and residence permit