# Visiting Romania with German Residence Permit

Tags: schengen, romania, german-residents

I am a Georgian citizen and living currently in Germany, possessing a German residence permit. Am I allowed to enter Romania for a few days? I know Romania is not in the Schengen area, but there are some confusing rules (for me) about Schengen visa holders. I would be grateful if anyone could give me a simple yes/no answer.

Comment: Please vote for my question to be closed because of being a duplicate :)

Comment: When we recently flew to Cluj, the Romanian border control argued for a couple of minutes with my friend at the passport booth because they had a German blue card residence permit and no German exit stamps in the passport. Apparently the Romanian border people were confused that they could leave Germany without getting their passport stamped. In the end they let them in, but it was inconvenient. The same argument again came up when we left Romania to go back to Berlin. I don't know if it was the same officer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040

> Do I need a visa?
>
> No
>
> - ​The holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national visas or **residence permits issued by Schengen Member States**.

I used to enter Romania in 2015 being a Ukraine citizen with a residence permit of a Schengen Member country. No visa was necessary.

Also, your question seems to be an exact duplicate of [Travel to Romania with a residence permit of Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74387/travel-to-romania-with-a-residence-permit-of-germany)